# Compile Library project with AndroidAnnotations and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-library, android-annotations

I am currently working on an Android library which is developed with AndroidAnnotations, and uses some Fragments. When it is compiled as an Android application, the code is fine and everything works. When it is compiled as an Android library, it breaks because it can't find any of the AndroidAnnotations generated classes.

I annotated each activity with `@EActivity(resName="activity_name")` instead of `@EActivity(R.layout.activity_name)`, and this corrects a few errors.

The problem that I encounter is that in some of those activities, I create dynamically some Fragments like this (for example) :

```
PhotoFragment fragment = PhotoFragment_.builder().someParams("a string param").build();
```

When I try to compile as an Android library, this call fails because it can't find the dynamically generated `PhotoFragment_` class. Is there a solution to make it work? Either by changing the way I create the Fragment, or by configuring AndroidAnnotations?

**EDIT 20/04/2016**

My `build.gradle`(module level) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Barcode library (ZXing)
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'

    // Android Annotations
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    // Android Bootstrap
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.1.0'

    // Gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    // Some auto-generated BS
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'

    // Robotium --> Emulate User Interaction on tests
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'

    // Android Testing
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

    // OkHTTP (HTTP Client Library)
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
}

apt {
    arguments {
        library 'true'
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are not seeing the generated classes inside the library, or the generated classes outside the library (for example in the app which uses the library)?

Comment: @WonderCsabo I am not seeing the generated classes inside the library. At this moment I'm just trying to compile the library as an AAR, and I can't :)

Comment: What is your AA version?

Comment: @WonderCsabo it's the 4.0.0 version

Comment: Are you using the `library` processing parameter?

Comment: @WonderCsabo In the build.gradle file?  Yes indeed. I'll paste my build.gradle tomorrow, if that helps

Comment: Thanks, please do that.

Comment: @WonderCsabo I updated my question to add the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: What is the version of the Android gradle plugin?

Comment: @WonderCsabo It's the 2.10 version

Comment: That can be the problem. :( Can you try with 2.0.0?

Comment: @WonderCsabo In Android Studio, I went into "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "Project", and I changed the Gradle version from 2.10 to 2.0.0. Same errors :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109782/discussion-between-wondercsabo-and-adrien-dos-reis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussion, it turned out there was a compilation error in the code (not related to the annotation processor). This is the AndroidAnnotations processor was not even called, and the classes were not generated.

The solution is fixing the "normal" compilation error, then annotation processors will run. It is hard, because the error will be buried in lots of generated class not found errors, so a thorough read is needed.